# Strptime() function won't give full python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following datetime which I'm trying to convert into a datetime object.

```
BEGINDATE = '20211121 09:00:00.000' 
start_date = datetime.strptime(BEGINDATE, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

I expect to see an output like when I run `datetime.now()`, i.e.

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 11, 9, 28, 45, 447007)
```

Instead, I get the following

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 21, 9, 0)
```

It cuts out two of the time arguments and also displays the minutes as 0 rather than 00. Have I formatted it wrong?

Comment: It would never display `00` for an integer literal because that's the same as `0`. And it doesn't bother showing values smaller than minutes if they're 0. You get the same result manually creating `datetime(2021, 11, 21, 9, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Why would you expect `9, 28, 45, ...` for `09:00:00.000`…? Bad example.

Comment: That's not what I meant @deceze. Was showing an example of what the datetime object looks like. Obviously, with different values for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you try with non zero values like this:

```
BEGINDATE = '20211121 09:01:02.120' 
start_date = datetime.strptime(BEGINDATE, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

you get:

```
 datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 21, 9, 1, 2, 120000)
```

so the the script is correct and the problem is in the data.

Comment: Thanks, strange that it doesn't let you specify 0 seconds but I'll change the start time string.

Comment: @XYZ123 it _does_ let you specify 0 seconds, there is no problem in the data (if there was there'd be a value error) it just doesn't bother _showing_ it in the default `__repr__`. If you want to control exactly how that gets displayed, use `strftime` (the "opposite" of `strptime`).

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe, didn't realise the date is still being stored correctly even if it's not being printed. Don't need it displayed, just stored correctly for some calculations. I'll change it back, cheers.